# How to run a file in pry that takes arguments

Tags: ruby, pry

I can start a pry session of a command line app like this

```
pry -r ./todo.rb
```

However, if I want to call the list function

```
pry -r ./todo.rb list
```

I'm getting an error message.

Without pry, I call the list function

```
ruby todo.rb list
```

This is the error message

```
/Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/repl_file_loader.rb:16:in `initialize': No such file: /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/Sites/todo/bin/list (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:161:in `new'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:161:in `load_file_through_repl'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/cli.rb:162:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/cli.rb:65:in `call'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/cli.rb:65:in `block in parse_options'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/cli.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/lib/pry/cli.rb:65:in `parse_options'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/pry-0.9.10/bin/pry:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/pry:19:in `load'
    from /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/pry:19:in `<main>'
```

**Source Code**

```
TODO_FILE = 'todo.txt'

def read_todo(line)
  line.chomp.split(/,/)
end

def write_todo(file,name,created=Time.now,completed='')
  file.puts("#{name},#{created},#{completed}")
end

command = ARGV.shift

case command
when 'new'
  new_task = ARGV.shift

  File.open(TODO_FILE,'a') do |file|
    write_todo(file,new_task)
    puts "Task added."
  end
when 'list'
  File.open(TODO_FILE,'r') do |file|
    counter = 1
    file.readlines.each do |line|
      name,created,completed = read_todo(line)
      printf("%3d - %s\n",counter,name)
      printf("      Created   : %s\n",created)
      unless completed.nil?
        printf("      Completed : %s\n",completed)
      end
      counter += 1
    end
  end
when 'done'
  task_number = ARGV.shift.to_i
  binding.pry

  File.open(TODO_FILE,'r') do |file|
    File.open("#{TODO_FILE}.new",'w') do |new_file|
      counter = 1
      file.readlines.each do |line|
        name,created,completed = read_todo(line)
        if task_number == counter
          write_todo(new_file,name,created,Time.now)
          puts "Task #{counter} completed"
        else
          write_todo(new_file,name,created,completed)
        end
        counter += 1
      end
    end
  end
  `mv #{TODO_FILE}.new #{TODO_FILE}`
end
```

**Update**

when I try

```
pry -r ./todo.rb -e list
```

I'm getting the following error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `list' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `pry --help`:

> `-e, --exec` A line of code to execute in context before the session starts

So, if your `list` method is defined on `main` (if you don't know, it probably is), then you can do this:

`pry -r ./todo.rb -e list`

---

## Update

Pry doesn't let you pass in arguments for scripts it loads (or at least it isn't documented). But all is not lost, you can call `pry` from your script. Just drop this at wherever you want to inspect:

```
require 'pry'; binding.pry
```

This will spawn a pry session that has access to all the local variables and methods.

Comment: thanks, but not sure if it's main. it's giving me this error when I try your solution. "NameError: undefined local variable or method `list' for main:Object"  Can you tell from the code? I updated the OP

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:
`ruby -rpry ./todo.rb -e list`